# Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Laptop cannot remain powered off. After shutdown, powers off, but then restarts

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, reboot

A few months again my laptop stopped being able to shut down. I do not recall any changes which might have caused the problem. I was using Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on a machine built by System76. I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit hoping this would solve the issue, but the problem persists. I can ONLY turn off the computer by pressing and holding the power button.

UPDATE OF PROBLEM: The unintended reboot only occurs when the laptop is plugged in, i.e. not on batter power.

The problem occurs when using the shutdown button on the upper right of the screen OR when I try command line options such as:

```
sudo shutdown now -P
```

or

```
sudo init 0
```

I have tried to solve it with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

but to no avail. I also tried booting from a live-cd into Ubuntu 13.04, then attempting the shutdown, again without success.

Comment: Just curious here, but what happens if you do `sudo init 0`? That should also halt the system.

Comment: This does not fix it, same problem occurs.

Comment: I don't have a real solution, but I do have a possible workaround: when your computer reboots, press <kbd>c</kbd> at the Grub boot scren to enter a custom command (if you don't see this screen, try holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while your system boots). Then type `halt` and press enter. That might shut your computer down.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a brand new Lenovo Flex 2 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After a lot of trial and error (online research, Lubuntu 14.10 live CD, installed Windows 7, updated BIOS) I fixed it by disabling xHCI on the BIOS. Hope it works for you, otherwise you might want to try unloading the xhci module BEFORE shutting down the laptop.